# Partition array such that sum of all the subarrays should be divisible by K and the length of each subarray should be >=2 or <=4. Python will be great

Tags: python, arrays

I got a question to solve to print the count of ways(and print all the subarrays) in which an array can be partitioned such that :-

1. The sum of all the subarrays formed should be divisible by K
2. The length of each subarray formed should be >=2 or <=4

At last print the different subarrays possible, which follows the above 2 conditions, along with the count.

The inputs are:-

1. 0<=N<=10^5
2. 0<=A[0],A[1],A[2],...,A[N-1]<=10^9
3. 1<=K<=10^9

Ex :

1. A=[6,3,3,8,4] -> Given Array
2. K=3 -> The number by which sum of all the subarrays should get
   divided

Possible subarrays according to the condition is 1 and that subarray is [[6,3],[3,8,4]] as length of all the subarrays are >=2 or <=4 and their sum is completely divisible by K(here K=3).

**Solution in python will be helpful